# How to exclude previous months of the current month?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP that displays the month then an IF statement inside the foreach that says IF the month is February then do the `li`:

```
$months = array('1' => 'January', '2' => 'February', '3' => 'March', '4' => 'April', '5' => 'May', '6' => 'June', '7' => 'July', '8' => 'August', '9' => 'September', '10' => 'October', '11' => 'November', '12' => 'December');
echo '<li><a class="by_month"></a><ul class="monthby" name="monthby">';
foreach($months as $month => $monthtitle):
  if ($month == '2'){
     echo '<li title="'.$monthtitle.'" rel="'.$month.'"><a href="#" title="'.$monthtitle.'">'.$monthtitle.'</a></li>';
  }
endforeach;
echo '</ul></li>';
```

How do I modify the above code to say IF the month is February, then exclude any previous months. Basically, I want to create a list of the current month and upcoming months but exclude past months of the year.

So, for example, if the month was November, the list would ONLY show November and December. It would exclude all previous months.

How can I do this? I image I need to do something with an IF statement, like I sort of started but using `date('n')` to get the current month then ignore previous months of the current month.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Array Keys to Ints and compare them with date('n') (n stands for month without a prefix zero)

```
foreach($months as $month => $monthtitle):
  if ((int)$month >= (int)date('n')){
     echo '<li title="'.$monthtitle.'" rel="'.$month.'"><a href="#" title="'.$monthtitle.'">'.$monthtitle.'</a></li>';
  }
endforeach;
```

Comment: What about doing that same code but include just 1 prev month. So, for example, if it was November it would have October, November and December?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! You're a life saver! Thanks so much for the help and quick responses! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check what is right now by using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. Specifically, the `m` parameter. To do that, you need to change this line:

```
if ($month == '2'){
```

into:

```
if ($month >= date('m')){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this can get you started:

```
<?php

$months = array('1' => 'January', '2' => 'February', '3' => 'March', '4' => 'April', '5' => 'May', '6' => 'June', '7' => 'July', '8' => 'August', '9' => 'September', '10' => 'October', '11' => 'November', '12' => 'December');
echo '<li><a class="by_month"></a><ul class="monthby" name="monthby">';

$a = date('n',time()); // current month (numeric)

for($i = $a; $i <= 12; $i++){
    echo '<li title="'.$months[$i].'" rel="'.$months[$i].'"><a href="#" title="'.$months[$i].'">'.$months[$i].'</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the built in [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function so you don't have to list the Months out manually in your code.  Then I might use the [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function to convert the months to timestamps and compare them based on that.  I've put some code below and here is a link to a [codepad](http://codepad.org/5s50m2aW).

```
$currentMonth = 2;
$currentTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $currentMonth, 1, 2012);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
  $iTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012);
  if ($iTime >= $currentTime) {
    $monthTitle = date('F', $iTime);
    echo '<li title="' . $monthTitle . '" rel="' . $i . '"><a href="#" title="' . $monthTitle . '">' . $monthTitle . '</a></li>';
  }
}
```